# Working with shutil and os: [Errno 2] No such file or directory 'folder'

Tags: python-3.x

```
import os, shutil

directory = 'C:\\Users\\MinJun\\Documents\\Python exercise solutions'
def move_files(_dir):
    for file in os.listdir(_dir): #check every file in directory
        if os.path.isdir(file): #if it is a folder, skip
            continue
        if file.endswith('.py'): #if file ends with .py, skip
            continue
        else:   #move file to newfolder, (it will automatically create one)
            shutil.move(file, directory.join('\\newfolder')) 

move_files(directory)
```

Hello, I am trying to move files that are not folders or .py files to a folder that does not exist (but will be created with `shutil.move`). I get an error in the `shutil` module:

> `FileNotFoundError`: [`Errno 2`] No such file or directory: 'graphics'

My folder 'graphics' is the first item in the directory.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
shutil.move(file, ''.join([directory, '\\newfolder'])
```

join does probably not work as you expected: https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html#str.join

If you `print(directory.join('\\newfolder'))` you can see what it resulted in, and that this path for sure does not exist.

There is also `os.path.join(path, *paths)`, which is sort of a "path-aware" string joining function.